# vector-of vs. vector in Clojure

Tags: vector, clojure

When would I use `vector-of` to create a vector, instead of the `vector` function.  Is the guideline to use `vector` most of the time and only for performance reason switch to `vector-of`?

I could not find good info on when to use `vector-of`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vector-of` is used for creating a vector of **a single primitive type**, `:int`, `:long`, `:float`, `:double`, `:byte`, `:short`, `:char`, or `:boolean`. It doesn't allow other types as it stores the values unboxed internally. So, if your vector need to include other types than those primitive types, you cannot use `vector-of`. But if you are sure that the vector will have data of a single primitive type, you can use `vector-of` for better performance.

```
user=> (vector-of :int 1 2 3 4 5)
[1 2 3 4 5]
user=> (vector-of :double 1.0 2.0)
[1.0 2.0]
user=> (vector-of :string "hello" "world")
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at user/eval5 (REPL:1).
Unrecognized type :string
```

As you can see, you should specify primitive type as an argument.

`vector` can be used to create a vector of any type.

```
user=> (vector 1 2.0 "hello")
[1 2.0 "hello"]
```

You can put any type when you use `vector`.

Also, there's another function `vec`, which is used for creating a new vector containing the contents of coll.

```
user=> (vec '(1 2 3 4 5))
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Usually, you can get the basic information of a function/macro from the repl, like the following.

```
user=> (doc vector-of)
-------------------------
clojure.core/vector-of
([t] [t & elements])
  Creates a new vector of a single primitive type t, where t is one
  of :int :long :float :double :byte :short :char or :boolean. The
  resulting vector complies with the interface of vectors in general,
  but stores the values unboxed internally.

  Optionally takes one or more elements to populate the vector.
```

Reference:

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector-of
- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector
- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec

Comment: I read about the different ways to create a vector.  I wanted to know if there are some guidelines that define when to use `vector-of` instead of `vector`.  So if I am creating a vector of primitive types, do I always use `vector-of`?

Comment: I don't know if there is a guide for this. One thing clear to me is that `vector-of` is a special function creating a vector of a single primitive type. I would use `vector` in most cases. But if the performance is important, I might try `vector-of` if my data is consist of a single primitive type.

Comment: If you use `vector` or `vac`, or most other ways in Clojure other than `vector-of`, to create a vector, and you only put 64-bit long integer values into it, they will be stored as Java `Long` objects, which are typically require 24 bytes of storage, rather than only the 8 bytes required for the 64-bit long value, because of Java object overhead.  Clojure programmers often do this, because it is convenient, and their vectors are not so large that it matters to them.  If you had huge vectors containing only longs, you can save a lot of memory by using `vector-of`.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody really ever uses `vector-of`. If you don't super care about performance, `vector` is fine, and if you do super care about performance you usually want a primitive array or some other java type. Honestly I would expect occasional weird snags when passing a `vector-of` to anything that expects an ordinary vector or sequence - maybe it works fine, but it's just such a rare thing to see that it wouldn't surprise me if it caused issues.